# Google Drive Error: Registered app required, either through authentication token or key param

Tags: google-drive-api

Suddenly today requests from my service attempting to insert a file into Google drive via the Drive API started to receive a 400 error.  The error indicates that a registered app is required, full error below.  An application was already registered in my Google Cloud console, however the applications name did not match the application name that was used by my service.  I renamed the services application name, however the error continues.

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "Registered app required, either through authentication token or key param.",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Registered app required, either through authentication token or key param."
}
```

Is there something else that needs to be setup, or could this be a delay in the renaming of the service?

EDIT: I'm able to list, update and download files however I cannot insert.

Comment: I have also noticed this error today and could not figure it out. Verified all mY cloud console settings and ensured the oauth credentials were correct. the service builds fine and I get a real, working access and refresh token but fails make drive api calls.

Comment: I've tried creating a brand new service account and api application however same error.

Comment: I am having the same problem on my app.  I verified all my Cloud Console settings.  I also updated to the latest google-api-services-drive-v2-rev107-1.17.0-rc.jar & google-api-java-client libraries and I am still getting the error.

Comment: @Nek are you using a service to connect to your drive account?  The account that you're connecting to is it a regular user account or is it an application owned account?  I fear that Google has changed the way that services work and are now enforcing it.  Looking at this: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts it appears to access a regular user account OAuth authentication is required and from what I see a service cannot impersonate a user anymore.

Comment: Confirming the same for our Drive app, we use the iOS SDK on their app implemented as advertised on their site only last month so I doubt there's anything new they are enforcing?

Comment: @amcc how does your app connect to the drive account?  Do you authenticate via OAuth or through a certificate?

Comment: @David I am connecting through regular user's accounts.  No service account is being used.  I am authenticating through OAuth2.  My basic usage during upload to Google Drive is pretty much identical to the quickstart guide shown on the Drive SDK site.  I use the GoogleAccountCredential when I build my drive service & GoogleAccountCredential.usingOauth2(context, driveScope).  This is on Android

Comment: @Nek thanks for the update, that is somewhat "good news" then, are connecting to a business version of Google Apps or free version or a regular Gmail version?

Comment: Regular free GMAIL version.  Just the run of the mill Google Drive that every user would get.  It's happening to all users of my app right now, and it just started today.  I tried multiple Gmail accounts and also went through the full Oauth authentication, granting the app permission to use my Drive Account.  I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Nek does it only happen with inserts? Can you list, update and download?

Comment: @David I can retrieve a list of folders without problems, so I am assuming LIST is OK.  My app doesn't download so I cannot test that.  But every insert is failing.

Comment: We're looking into it

Comment: @SteveBazyl thanks Steve, all is well now.  What is the best way of notifying Google of these types of issues (albeit they're very rare).  I tried calling Google Apps Support, however that did not seem to really go any where.

Answer (score 1):

This same issue just started to happen to us today - and we made no changes.  I (think I) submitted a bug report to Google about this.  Will keep digging..

UPDATE: I created a new project with private key and client ID/email and I get the same error with this new project as well.  This appears to be some bug with Google Drive API service.

Comment: Yes, this even happens with Google's DrEdit sample app at the moment.  Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

It happens today on my app too. I guess their service is having problem today